# Converting a date by string format to nsdate result one day before string date

Tags: ios, nsdate

I searched about my problem but I did not find any help related...

The story:
The user create a continues event by name, start date, end date and note, so saves all fields on the Sqlite database. The both dates format are "yyyy-MM-dd".
After that, when user want to do an action on event, the app checks the date that user selected by start and end date and if the entered date is before start date or after end date notifies user.

The problem:
I, as an user, created an event from 18-8-2012 to 18-9-2012. Then I put log on 18-8-2012 and I  was notified. I debugged app. and I was amazed. the date object from string with format "yyyy-MM-dd" is "2012-08-17 19:30:00 +0000".
The code is:

```
           #define kPickerDate @"yyyy-MM-dd"
           NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
           [formatter setDateFormat:kPickerDate];
           NSDate *sDate = [formatter dateFromString:start_date]; 
           NSDate *eDate = [formatter dateFromString:exam_date];
```

How does app that??????????????

Comment: It's giving you the date in a different time zone.

Comment: it's always good to include some code

Comment: I'm in +03:30 GMT time zone,if your idea is true, I should give the 08:30:00 GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an NSDate object using a better method. First amend the @interface for NSDate (you can do this anywhere). To do this, put this in your header file.

```
@interface NSDate (missingFunctions) 
+ (NSDate *)dateWithYear:(NSInteger)year month:(NSInteger)month day:(NSInteger)day;
@end
```

Then in the main file put:

```
@implementation NSDate (missingFunctions)
+ (NSDate *)dateWithYear:(NSInteger)year month:(NSInteger)month day:(NSInteger)day {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setYear:year];
    [components setMonth:month];
    [components setDay:day];

    //BUT MOST IMPORTANTLY:
    [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [components setHour:hour];
    [components setMinute:minute];
    [components setSecond:second];

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}   
@end
```

Then from anywhere in code call (for example):

```
[NSDate dateWithYear:1969 month:8 day:15];
```

And it will return an NSDate as per your request in the right time zone. You can change which time zone to use also by reading more about [NSTimeZone](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTimeZone) at the official apple docs.

**Note** I can't take credit for writing this code, but I can vouch for it working.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't safe. I've tried this. It only works until daylight savings adjusts your clock back an hour. At that point, your NSDates will point to a different day.

Comment: @StevenFisher Would you offer a solution (following this method) that might work instead? If what is important is the day month and year and the hour minute and second are irrelevant to the NSDate Object, then wouldn't it be possible to set the hour to midday and not have any problems? Perhaps setting the timezone manually to UTC is a better solution for many problems, but it seems unnecessary for this particular one.

Comment: That solves the DST case, but it wouldn't solve travelling. I had an app that was about as locale-specific as you could possibly get (it was information for a school) and I still needed to make the switch to UTC.

Comment: Look at it this way: Using local time means you need to find a solution for every home time zone including daylight savings time swings and travel. I'm not sure even using high noon works; with a potential +13/-13 swing, it might push you to a different date. Using UTC means you need to set the `timeZone` property of the `NSDateTimeFormatter`. It's not that using UTC is unnecessarily hard; it's actually quite a bit easier.

Comment: OK maybe I need a clarification but: Say you have an event that you want to fire on an NSDate at noon. You add this NSDate to say a notification. Would that notification fire at noon for UTC on that day, potentially not the timezone that you would really want? Am I wrong?

Comment: @StevenFisher ^ (In case you didn't get a notification) I am really interested in hearing your answer.

Comment: Or, if only the day, month and year are important (or even just day and month) would it be wise to instead just store an instance of NSDateComponents? In that case, it would be a timeless date object.

Comment: I don't know how notifications handle time zones. I'd be very interested in finding out. If you posted this as a question, maybe someone else would know though. :) My **guess** is that if you set a notification for noon and moved an hour over, it'd go off at 11am or 1pm. I think using an NSDateComponents object would be pretty reasonable, but it's hard to beat year-month-day in storage for  debugging and transparency. It's hard to over-estimate how wonderful plain text is in files.

Answer (score 10):

An `NSDate` is not just a date, but also a time.

You need to check this at every stage:

- **Is your date being built correctly when parsed?** It should be midnight UTC, rather than midnight local. You're probably using a `NSDateFormatter` for this. Make sure it's time zone is set to UTC.
- **Are your dates being stored in SQLite correctly?** Again, make sure you're storing it as UTC. If you're parsing it correctly, though, this should work.
- **Are you formatting the output correctly?**  probably using a `NSDateFormatter` for this. Make sure it's time zone is set to UTC.

Only once all three pieces are perfect will you be free of potential bugs here.

To set the time zone of a date formatter, use:

```
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"UTC"];
```

Do not try to work around this by adopting local time.

The problem with local times:

- In many time zones the time changes a couple times a year with Daylight Savings Time. That one hour difference will throw the date part of your times onto a previous day!
- If the user is in a time zone without Daylight Savings Time, they may travel to a different time zone. Again, the date part of your times may be thrown off a day.

The only safe thing to do is use UTC everywhere.

(I actually kind of pity people who live in UTC; they're not forced to shake these bugs out of their apps!)